# How to show order details in Magento transaction email templates?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to show customer name and order id in transaction email templates. But these values are coming dynamically.

I create a email template having store id 1. I am calling that email template in phtml page. But how I send order id and name to template page which is coming dynamically.

The code in phtml page

```
$vars = Array('name' => '$name',
              'orderId' => '$ordernumber');   
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
$mailTemplate=Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
->setTemplateSubject('mailSubject')
->sendTransactional(1, $sender, $email, $name, $vars, $storeId);
            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                   echo "no send";
                }
```

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, Prince? It looks useful, but you do not seem to have replied/voted on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please in phtml first load the order that you want to send.

then fetch the parameters needed from them and pass to transnational template

You can change send and recipient as per you  need

```
$customer_name   = 'John Doe'; //set dynamically as per you need
$order_id = '1110000'; //set dynamically as per you need

// Here is where we can define custom variables to go in our email template!

$email_template_variables = array(
    'customer_name' => $customerName,
  'order_id ' => $order_id 
    // Other variables for our email template.
);

$templateId = 1;
                // Get Store ID    
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
                // Send Transactional Email
                Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                ->sendTransactional($templateId,  Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),  Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT), null,   $email_template_variables        );
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

Your template maust include the array variable to set in email sent

```
ie. {{var customer_name}}  {{var order_id}}
```